# Replace a character in [] with another

Tags: node.js, regex, node-modules, regex-group, node-red

Can anybody help with replacing the below?

I have the below text:

```
[$.abc],[CONTAINS],[-],[],[add 123]
```

I want the output to look like:

```
[$.abc],[CONTAINS],[list],[],[add 123]
```

So basically I want to replace `[-]` with `[list]` using regex in Nodejs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This way: Find `\[-\]` replace `[list]`. You don't need regex to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex:

```
let phrase = "[$.abc],[CONTAINS],[-],[],[add 123]"
let newPhrase = phrase.replace('[-]','[list]')
```

or for many

```
let newPhrase = phrase.split('-').join("list")
//'[$.abc],[CONTAINS],[list],[],[add 123]'
```